# Icon disappears when clicked on it in tab view controller

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have created an app using tab view controller. I have three different pages. When i click on the second and third icons, it becomes blue how normal tab view icons look like. However my first icon disappears. I do not have any code to configure this. I do this using the storyboard. I have looked through different questions but none helped me.

Comment: The information you are giving is not really going to help. You need to provide a reproducible example or code.

Comment: but my code does not affect my icons

Comment: you probably need to add proper tab bar icons not random images

Comment: what do you mean by proper

Comment: i did design it myself

Comment: Check This Answer by garrettmurray at the link. It might help you. Let me know if it you still can't resolve it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18068597/what-size-of-image-should-be-for-tabbar

Comment: thanks. it helped me resolve my issue