# iOS Custom Tab Bar

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, iso

I am looking to implement a custom Tab Bar in iOS where selected item is bigger size than the rest of the tabs and peeks out over the content similar to this screenshot. [image]

Could someone point to a tutorial of how to accomplish this preferably in Swift?

Comment: https://github.com/satishVekariya/SUITabView

Answer (score 8):

I faced with this task several times. I found a lot of tutorials but I've never found one that gives the ability to create a center button that part of it is out of the tab bar.

At the end, I created an approach to have it done correctly. I implemented a simple example project with instructions how to do that. Please check my [Custom Tabbar Center Button](https://github.com/drrost/Custom-Tabbar-Cetner-Button) repo as an example.

One more benefit of it it's center button hides correctly with the tab bar when you use `Hide Button Bar on Push` property.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> A UITabBar contains an array of UITabBarItems, which inherit from
>   UIBarItem. But unlike UIBarButtonItem that also inherits from
>   UIBarItem, there is no API to create a UITabBarItem with a customView.
>
> So instead of trying to create a custom UITabBarItem, we’ll just
>   create a regular one and then put the custom UIButton on top of the
>   UITabBar

Not swift, but should be easily translated.

https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/RaisedCenterTabBar

This one is Swift:
https://github.com/itsKaynine/SwiftRaisedTab

Source code for a similar question, using Swift 3:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36016377/300897

Comment: Thanks for this. Its one possible approach. But I'm looking to have a selected tab raised not just a center one. These solutions place a custom button at the center, any idea how I can do this for any selected tab not just the center one?

Comment: Ah, I see. I misunderstood your intent. I'll post back if I find anything.