# How to add a button to a Tab Bar Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I mean, not a UITabBarItem, an UIButton. For example, in the Deezer app, the middle button shows a view with an animation that covers the entire screen. I don't want the button to be rounded. Just to execute the action.

Comment: The TabBar compatible with their own buttons not UIButton

Comment: So is there any workaround to make this work?

Comment: You don't need a UIButton to do what you've mentioned. It's as simple as adding a target.

Comment: @BenjaminLowry, can you, please, show me how?

Comment: @user6603599 Perhaps you're looking for animate the buttons transform! Right?

Comment: @Mannopson, I want that when the button is pressed, a view controller appears from bottom to top, and to hide it by swiping from top to bottom.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make custom button on Tab Bar rounded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36014073/make-custom-button-on-tab-bar-rounded)

Comment: @ThomasClemensen, no, it isn't. My target isn't to make the button rounded

Comment: @user6603599 https://youtu.be/G5UkS4Mrepo Hope it helps you

Comment: @Mannopson, yes, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very simplistic example. You'll still have to modify it to fit your needs, but if you have a UIBarButtonItem called `button` that you've added to your navigationBar, you should be able to do something like this, in `viewDidLoad`

```
button.action = #selector(showView)
```

Then you just need to create a function to be called.

```
func showView() {
    let myView = UIView()
    self.view.addSubview(myView)
}
```

Of course this has no animations, but again this is just to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks! I will write an animation. How can I make it disappear by swiping from top to bottom?

Comment: Well, I'm not 100% sure, but I think using a pan gesture recognizer might work.

Comment: Yes, but how can I do this?

Comment: You can refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24215117/how-to-recognize-swipe-in-all-4-directions) for inspiration. Then just dismiss the VC in the selector parameter.

Comment: @user6603599 No problem :)

Comment: Value of type 'UITabBarItem' has no member 'action'

Comment: I noticed now that you have written "UIBarButtonItem". It's a UITabBarItem.