# TabBarController adding custom button not clickable issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I'm adding a custom button over the **tabBarController** and the button becomes over the **tabBarController** it is clicked when I hit it inside the **tabBarController** it is working fine but if I hit the part outside the **tabar** it is not clickable.

[image]

```
class CustomBar: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    func addButton() {

        mainBasketView.frame =  CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width / 2 - 30, y: -20, width: 58, height: 58)
        mainBasketView.basketButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnNewMoment_Action), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        tabBar.addSubview(mainBasketView)
    }
}
```

I don't want to add it as `view.addSubView` because the view doesn't disappear when I call `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed`

Comment: stuck in same problem  ... did you find any solution ??

Answer (score 0):

you should increase your tabar height  its 49 default  and your button is 58

```
extension UITabBar {
        override open func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
            return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 60)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I want to keep that design which looks outside the tabbar. Isn't possible?

Comment: so check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36014073/make-custom-button-on-tab-bar-rounded

Comment: In this answer I found that people complaining about hidesBottomBarWhenPushed which doesn't remove the button in the centre. I made a test project which shows the same issue.