# Keep Tabbar when click on central button

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am using following layout design [image]

but when i click on central circular button it's cover the whole screen ... i want to make `tabbar` visible on every click ...

I try to open `ViewController` as a sub view with following code

```
  guard let StoreVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StoreVC") else { return }
   StoreVC.view.frame = self.view.bounds
   self.addChild(StoreVC)
   self.view.addSubview(StoreVC.view)
   StoreVC.didMove(toParent: self)
```

but its cover the entire screen including `tabbar` ..

i try following code but still does't work as expected ...

```
       guard let StoreVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StoreVC") else { return }
       self.definesPresentationContext = true
       StoreVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
       self.present(StoreVC,animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Embedding it in a navigation controller also does't work ...

This circular button is not the part of `Tabbar` but i want it to act like a `tabBarItem` ...

if i make it part of `tabbar` it upper part not click able ...

just like explain in this question [TabBarController adding custom button not clickable issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45881696/tabbarcontroller-adding-custom-button-not-clickable-issue)