# Custom tab button position error on iphone x

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode9, iphone-x

I add custom button to my tabbar with following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36014073/make-custom-button-on-tab-bar-rounded/43271963#43271963) answer.

```
var menuButtonFrame: CGRect = menuButton.frame

//menuButtonFrame.origin.y = tabBar.frame.y + tabBar.frame.height - menuButtonFrame.height

menuButtonFrame.origin.y = view.bounds.height - menuButtonFrame.height
menuButtonFrame.origin.x = self.view.bounds.width / 2 - menuButtonFrame.size.width / 2
menuButton.frame = menuButtonFrame

menuButton.backgroundColor = Colors.mainColor
menuButton.layer.cornerRadius = menuButtonFrame.height/2
self.view.addSubview(menuButton)
```

when i tested on simulator it works good. but when i tested on Iphone X simulator it displays under tabbar.

[image: IPhone 8]

[image: IPhone X]

I tried to align buttons `origin.y` value to tabbar bottom (commented line) but it didn't work again.

Should i use iphone x specific alignment or is there more clean solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add centerButton in UIView. Add in tabBar

```
func addMenuButton() {

    let menuWidth: CGFloat = 64    //let height & width same as 64

    let menuButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: (tabBar.frame.width / 2) - (menuWidth / 2), y: 0, width: menuWidth, height: menuWidth))

    menuButton.backgroundColor = .red
    menuButton.layer.cornerRadius = menuWidth/2
    tabBar.addSubview(menuButton)    //Add in tabBar instead of UIView
}
```

[image]