# Add Button To Center Of Tabbar In Xib File

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, nib

I create custom tabbar view with xib file and UIView class. I have a button in center of tabbar view and this button is not totally in my tabbar view .a Half of button is in tabbar view area and another one is in top of tabbar view . action of button doesn't work when i click the top of this button . Now my **question is how i can create this button when click all side of it action work Properly ?**
[image]

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36016377/4056108)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make custom button on Tab Bar rounded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36014073/make-custom-button-on-tab-bar-rounded)